# Browsing play.google.com without opening Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, chrome-for-android

When I try opening play.google.com in Google Chrome, it redirects to the Google Play Store app. I want to access the Play Store from my browser so I can easily get links to different apps for sharing. Thanks for being such a helpful group!

Comment: Use an alternate browser such as Firefox or the Samsung browser?

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of this, but hoped not to resort to it. I guess I have an excuse to install Opera Touch again. Cheers

Comment: Have you tired entering play.google.com into chrome's address bar?

Comment: qblueRed, I thought I had already tried that, but it just worked. I guess my problem was trying to tap links to apps